# React-leaflet problem to create <Marker> <Popup> instance dynamic

Tags: dynamic, leaflet, popup, marker, react-leaflet

I would like to create a react-leaflet object dynamically. Normal leaflet objects work, but react-leaflet do not.
Code example on:
https://codesandbox.io/s/show-problem-react-leaflet-marker-popup-object-hm0o8?file=/src/MapView.js

Left click shows the desired behavior with leaflet objects and right click the problem with react-leaflet.

problem code:

```js
var lat = e.latlng.lat;
var lon = e.latlng.lng;
// create popup contents
    
// use <Marker> from react-leaflet
var newMarker = <Marker position={[lat, lon]}>
  {/* use Edit Popup */}
  <Popup editable open>   
    Your stylable content here.
  </Popup>
</Marker>;
    
// Problem addTo(map) 
newMarker.addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newMarker` is a react element.  You can't call the leaflet method `addTo` on it, because it is not a leaflet `L.Marker` instance.

If you want to be able to manage the markers through react, you would need to keep a state variable which is an array of coordinates.  On map click, you can add the coordinate to that array, and then render a series of `<Marker />` elements from that.

In your event handlers, you're simply going to capture the position of the click and pass it to a callback `setMarkers`:

```js
function MyRightClickEventHandler({ setMarkers }) {
  useMapEvents({
    contextmenu: (e) => {
      setMarkers(e.latlng);
    }
  });
  return null;
}
```

`setMarkers` is a callback to `setState` on your primary MapView component, which adds the `latlng` to the state variable, which contains an array of `latlngs`:

```js
// inside you'r MapContainer:
<MyRightClickEventHandler
  setMarkers={(markers) =>
    this.setState({ 
      MarkerArray: [...this.state.MarkerArray, markers] 
    })
  }
/>
```

Then map over the latlngs that are in that state variable, if there are any:

```js
{this.state.MarkerArray &&
  this.state.MarkerArray.map((latlng) => (
    <Marker position={latlng}>
      <Popup editable removable>
        Thanks for using my editable popup plugin!
      </Popup>
    </Marker>
  ))}
```

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/show-problem-react-leaflet-marker-popup-object-forked-xpz57)

Note that if you're going to use the `editable`, `removable`, or `open` props on editable popups rendered dynamically from an array, be sure to read my section on [using editable popups rendered from a dynamic state array](https://github.com/slutske22/react-leaflet-editable-popup#with-state-management) - it can get hairy if you're not careful.  Feel free to ask questions in the comments if you run into problems.